# how do we normally greet when some one meet around 2pm to 3.30pm?

Tags: time

How do we normally greet when some one meet around 2pm to 3.30pm ?

I know normally after 12.00pm, we called "Good Afternoon", 
But what if the time is around 2pm to 3.30pm ?

Usage : When I'm greeting at the meeting.

Comment: Normally, we'd say "hey!" or "how are you?", "how ya' doin'?" or something like that. I can hardly imagine a situation where I'd actually say "good afternoon".

Comment: Greetings have various forms based on the participants and context. Time is only one factor. More detail is needed here.

Comment: If the time of day is between 2:00 p.m. and 3:30 p.m., it **is** in the afternoon. Please use the [edit] link to add to your question by telling us why you think _Good afternoon_ is not an appropriate greeting during the afternoon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you say "good afternoon from 12.00 noon to 16.59.  So if the time is around 2pm to 3.30pm, you say "good afternoon".

Answer (score 0):

We should greet "Good Afternoon" at 12.00p.m to 4.00 p.m.